Angular 18 and .NET 8 C# deploy to Heroku
I have deployed two apps on Heroku: one for frontend (Angular18) and the second for backend (.NET 8 C#). And I get the problem when I tried to connect frontend to backend. My backend is working good. I tested it for Swagger to put something there so its works fine.
So when I try to connect my frontend to backend, I get this error:
From terminal
2024-12-20T18:29:24.208137+00:00 app\[web.1\]: info: Yarp.ReverseProxy.Forwarder.HttpForwarder\[9\]
2024-12-20T18:29:24.208150+00:00 app\[web.1\]: Proxying to http://localhost:8080/auth/login HTTP/2 RequestVersionOrLower
2024-12-20T18:29:24.209577+00:00 app\[web.1\]: warn: Yarp.ReverseProxy.Forwarder.HttpForwarder\[48\]
2024-12-20T18:29:24.209580+00:00 app\[web.1\]: Request: An error was encountered before receiving a response.
2024-12-20T18:29:24.209580+00:00 app\[web.1\]: System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Connection refused (localhost:8080)
2024-12-20T18:29:24.209580+00:00 app\[web.1\]: ---\> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (111): Connection refused
20241220T18:29:24.209581+00:00app\[web.1\]:atSystem.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)


Look for your error message. It is saying that the YARP is trying to access an app in the address http://localhost:8080 it does not exist in your Heroku network. Each app on Heroku functions as a container service, so you need to read the documentation to understand what needs to be done for the network to identify your app or if you need to access it from a public network.

in my server.js for fronted, I have this code:
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
const server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(PORT, () => {
console.log(Server is running on port ${PORT});
console.log(Environment: ${process.env.NODE_ENV});
console.log(ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT: ${process.env.ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT});
});  maybe here I need to change this "const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;"?
